# Adding Yandex Satellite TMS via QGIS Python console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console, tile-map-service, yandex

I add a TileMapService layer to QGIS map window using a Python console. But added layer is not displayed. What is wrong?

```py
tmsLayer_name = 'YandexSat'

uri = "url=http://sat04.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=sat&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&zmax=19&zmin=0&type=xyz"

tms_layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri,tmsLayer_name,'wms')

if not tms_layer.isValid():
    print ("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(tms_layer)
```

At the same time QMS perfectly displays the same layer:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `uri` looks good:

```
uri = "url=http://sat04.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=sat&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&zmax=19&zmin=0&type=xyz"
```

but in certain places it requires the [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

As soon as you convert the `uri` into:

```
uri = "url=http://sat04.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l%3Dsat%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=19&zmin=0&type=xyz"
```

*where:*

```
%3D <=> =
%26 <=> &
%7B <=> {
%7D <=> }
```

it should work, see image below

[image: result]